Script to add hosts entries using txt file
I need a cmd scritp to add multiple lines to hosts file from a txt file.
I've found in this post a script by Tony
@echo off
TITLE Modifying your HOSTS file
ECHO.

:: BatchGotAdmin
:-------------------------------------
REM  --> Check for permissions
>nul 2>&1 "%SYSTEMROOT%\system32\cacls.exe" "%SYSTEMROOT%\system32\config\system"

REM --> If error flag set, we do not have admin.
if '%errorlevel%' NEQ '0' (
    echo Requesting administrative privileges...
    goto UACPrompt
) else ( goto gotAdmin )

:UACPrompt
    echo Set UAC = CreateObject^("Shell.Application"^) > "%temp%\getadmin.vbs"
    set params = %*:"="
    echo UAC.ShellExecute "cmd.exe", "/c %~s0 %params%", "", "runas", 1 >> "%temp%\getadmin.vbs"

    "%temp%\getadmin.vbs"
    del "%temp%\getadmin.vbs"
    exit /B

:gotAdmin
    pushd "%CD%"
    CD /D "%~dp0"
:--------------------------------------

:LOOP
SET Choice=
SET /P Choice="Do you want to modify HOSTS file ? (Y/N)"

IF NOT '%Choice%'=='' SET Choice=%Choice:~0,1%

ECHO.
IF /I '%Choice%'=='Y' GOTO ACCEPTED
IF /I '%Choice%'=='N' GOTO REJECTED
ECHO Please type Y (for Yes) or N (for No) to proceed!
ECHO.
GOTO Loop


:REJECTED
ECHO Your HOSTS file was left unchanged.
ECHO Finished.
GOTO END


:ACCEPTED
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
::Create your list of host domains
for /F "tokens=1,2 delims=  " %%A in (%WINDIR%\System32\drivers\etc\storedhosts.txt) do (
    SET _host=%%B
    SET _ip=%%A
    SET NEWLINE=^& echo.
    ECHO Adding !_ip!       !_host!
    REM REM ::strip out this specific line and store in tmp file
    type %WINDIR%\System32\drivers\etc\hosts | findstr /v !_host! > tmp.txt
    REM REM ::re-add the line to it
    ECHO %NEWLINE%^!_ip!        !_host! >> tmp.txt
    REM ::overwrite host file
    copy /b/v/y tmp.txt %WINDIR%\System32\drivers\etc\hosts
    del tmp.txt 
)

ipconfig /flushdns
ECHO.
ECHO.
ECHO Finished, you may close this window now.
GOTO END

:END
ECHO.
PAUSE
EXIT

Example "storedhosts.txt" (tab delimited)
127.0.0.1   mysite.com
168.1.64.2  yoursite.com
192.1.0.1   internalsite.com

But it not works form me, it delete all HOSTS file and just write the last one entry.
When script starts i get this error for every ip
FIND: Parameter format not correct" and "FINDSTR: Write error" with Pipes
Someone can help me to modify this script please? Thank you

If you have a problem with this script by Tony, then post a comment beneath their answer, and wait for them to assist you, (especially as it is not the accepted answer, and is based upon code from two other non accepted answers to the same question). We shouldn't be trying to diagnose an issue before they have themselves looked into it.

I didn't test this, but copy /? reveals the following:

To append files, specify a single file for destination, but multiple files
for source (using wildcards or file1+file2+file3 format).

So, I would simply replace this command:
copy /b/v/y tmp.txt %WINDIR%\System32\drivers\etc\hosts

By:
copy /b/v/y tmp.txt+%WINDIR%\System32\drivers\etc\hosts %WINDIR%\System32\drivers\etc\hosts


it doesn't work despite the change
